# Is there a guide for copyright for countries other than the US?

Tags: publishing, copyright, law

I've seen some questions that deal with copyright issues and it is clear that this is an international group and we could all benefit from having access to info about copyright as it relates to our own country. I'm in the US and I'm pretty well versed on copyright for a non-lawyer, but laws in different countries will obviously vary.

If we are using, creating, transferring, buying, or loaning ebooks, copyright applies, so it would make sense in this group.

Comment: @mathweaver I believe you're missing some information in your last sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this issue will be important to this group, I found a couple of resources that will explain copyright terms in different countries.

The data on the first site hasn't been updated in a while but it does include info on fair use.
[Foreign Copyright Laws
Tree-view chart on Foreign Copyright Law](http://chart.copyrightdata.com/ch08A.php#top)

The good thing about the above site is that it is exhaustively cited so people can at least see where they can get started in researching their own copyright questions.

There is also good ol' wikipedia with a list of country's copyright lengths.
[List of countries' copyright lengths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries%27_copyright_lengths)

If you know of others, add them and we can build a useful resource.

Answer (score 2):

This [guide](http://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/okbooks.html) is quite useful from Univ. of Pennsilvania.
[Copyright Watch](http://www.copyright-watch.org/) is also helpful, but the information isn't so direct. You have to really dig through legal documents.